# Xcode Shows No Outlets

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, storyboard, iboutlet

I'm using Xcode 4.2 and I'm trying to link outlets to my viewController but Xcode shows no outlets

here's my [AppDelegate.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E780T.jpg)

By The Way before I do this I have made the same project with same codes but I have deleted it unintentionally and I've have completely deleted and re-installed xcode but with no success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure the viewController on the storyboard have the PeekPagedScrollViewController class

Comment: ^Yes, that was the problem :) thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the class `PeekPaged...` to your viewController in the Storyboard?